# Is there a way to make it so the /clear command takes a certain amount of items with a strict amount?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have a map with emeralds, and I want it to take a certain amount. **HOWEVER,** I want it to take 3 emeralds and only 3 emeralds. Is there a way I can do that? I know I can do `/clear @p emerald 0 3`, but there's no minimum amount. Is there a command to do that? No more, no less.

Comment: What do you mean take emeralds?

Comment: So only clear any emeralds if the player has exactly 3 (no more, no less)?

Comment: Yeah. No more, no less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use CommandStats in order to count the number of items the player has, stored as a score.

### Prerequisites

Objective to hold the score for each player.

```
/scoreboard objectives add ItemCount dummy
```

The trigger to apply to players. Note that if new players can join in at any time, this may need to run on a clock. This trigger activates whenever the player runs a command that targets items in inventories, and will set their own "ItemCount" score equal to the return value of the `AffectedItems` trigger.

```
/stats entity @a set AffectedItems @a[c=1] ItemCount
```

The target of the trigger must be tracked in the objective prior in order to have their score changed. This may also need to run on a clock.

```
/scoreboard players add @a ItemCount 0
```

### Detection

The following must be run in numerical order, on a clock if necessary.

1. Cause players to run a `/clear` command that removes 0 items. While their inventory is untouched, it sends the `AffectedItems` trigger the total number of items that matched in their inventory.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /clear @a[c=1] minecraft:emerald 0 0
   ```
2. Now players will have an "ItemCount" score equal to the number of emeralds in their inventory. You can target them based on that score to remove 3 emeralds only if the player had at least 3 emeralds:

   ```
   /clear @a[score_ItemCount_min=3] minecraft:emerald 0 3
   ```

### Why not NBT?

While you *could* mark players based on their inventory data with NBT:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add hasEmeralds {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:3b}]}
```

This **requires** that the player has a single inventory slot dedicated to **exactly** 3 emeralds. If the player had a size-4 stack of emeralds in an inventory slot, it fails. If the player had 3 emeralds in their inventory, but they were spread out in size-1 stacks, it also fails.